# PowerBi Combo Chart

Tags: powerbi, command, linechart, column-chart, combo-chart

With Month as X-axis, Count as Y-axis, Year as legend, Cumulative count as Secondary Y-axis, I only want to drag cumulative count or one new measure once to the line y-axis to display lines according to the legend (3 years in total) so I want 3 lines (years) in a line and clustered chart. Any ideas with proof?

Normally, it's one line & multiple columns by year but I want 3 lines without manually creating 3 measures. Drag once is enough.